# Auto generate email based on username in WordPress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I've had some trouble getting this to work in the new user registration form, what I want is to have the email field automatically filled with a dummy email generated based on the username.

For example, if the user inputs `user1` the generated email should be `user1@test.com`

I want it to be done in the new user form in case a user has a real email it can be specified instead of the dummy one.

What I've tried was some javascript and jQuery, but I can't get it to work, you can see the code below.

```
jQuery('#user_login').on('input propertychange paste', function()
{
    var x = $('#user_login').val();
    $($email).val( x + '@test.com');
});
```

Current javascript

```
<script>
$("user_login").change(function AutoEmail() {
    var x= $('#user_login').val();
    $('#email').val(x+'@test.com');
});
</script>
```

Also, where should this code be placed?, I'm a bit lost on the way things are organized in WordPress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```js
    $(document).on( "input", "#user_login", function AutoEmail() {
        var x= $('#user_login').val();
      if( x != "" ) {
          $('#email').val(x+'@test.com');
      } else {
         $('#email').val("");
      }
       
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Username: <input type = "text" id = "user_login"><br>
Email: <input type = "text" id = "email">
```

Comment: Nice, i can see the code snippet working, I've put the code inside a <script> tag in user-new.php, is it OK for it to be there or should the code be placed somewhere else?

Comment: Place it in header, that is advisable :)

Comment: Hmm can't get it to work, i tried inside user-new.php file but no luck

Comment: By the way email field if of type email and the user_login is of type text, i don't know if that might have to do with it, i also have autocomplete turned off in those fields, just mentioning in case that could cause any problems with the script

Comment: That's not a problem. Look for console log for error. Or add `$ = jQuery` and make sure that jQuery is included!! Thanks